# Are there any limitations on where PHP code can go inside a file?

Tags: php, tags

Can you put PHP anywhere in a file? Inside tags and quotes? For example, is something like this guaranteed to work (even though it isn't always recognized by an IDE's syntax highlighter):

```
<tr><tbody <?php if(!$row) echo "style='display: none;'"; ?>>
<!-- stuff that we only want to show if $row exists -->
</tbody></tr>
```

Or for example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=<?= echo $searchTerm; ?>"</a>
```

I know I can test this sort of thing on my machine, but I'm wondering if it is guaranteed/defined behavior and if there are any edge cases that *don't* work that I've missed.

Also, is there good reason *not* to do this? Is it dangerous because the next person looking at the code might miss it? Should I put a comment in? Does having to add a comment defeat the purpose of this method - succinctness?

Comment: PHP is _always_ processed before any client-side markup (HTML, CSS, etc). Note that your second example is using short-tags, which are not always enabled.

Comment: Simple answer is no, there are no limitations because PHP is interpreted before the HTML

Comment: This is literally the first chapter of the php documentation: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I wasn't sure if there were some things the PHP parser skipped over, but it makes sense that it doesn't. To the downvoter(s), please comment so I can improve my question(s).

Comment: @ccKep I've read that page before, but it doesn't say anything about whether there are any special cases. Ideally that sort of thing would be clearly written down, but you never know if an edge case will be hidden away in another part of the manual.

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: `everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can put the php tags anywhere in the page (html) there is no stopping you on that.

If we go under the hood, your web server sends the code to the php interpreter via a handler and merges the output with your static html file and sends the merged file as the response.

To add to my answer, developers usually go for MVC based frameworks so that the php code inside html page is restricted to only printing the variables and the business logic is performed in the controllers. I personally prefer CakePHP. Apart from that you might not want to put code that manipulates session or performs redirection between html tags else you will recieve the headers already set error as you have already printed certain html code before modifying the headers.

Comment: Sorry i was on the mobile app (first time) didnt find the edit answer option earlier